# Google Map standard Moroccan view without Western Sahara

Tags: google-maps

Users of Google Map in Morocco do not see the border with Western Sahara and the territory name "western sahara" does not appear on any Google Map devices for these users. This is standard on Google Map you open on a device in Morocco.
I try to find a Google MAP API or library to use to have exact same behavior than above.
I have not found anything on Google Map help documents or stackoverflow.
(Same in many countries with disputed territories like Korea with Japan Sea etc)

Many thanks!
S

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the JS API, you can use Region localization in your call to the Maps JavaScript API to show the map without the Western Sahara frontier, by setting the Region code to MA (for Morocco):

You can read more about Region and Language localization on the Localization page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization

You can use the Localization Demo on that page to show the difference in the map by setting different Region codes:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization#localization-demo
(the map demo centers on Poland, but you can drag the map to show western Sahara after changing the Language or Region drop-downs)

Also in the future please include enough information (like a working reproducible sample) so that other people will be able to understand you better and reproduce your issue.

Comment: This has just **nothing** to do with the question asked.